# port ksh if condition to bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have this if statement in ksh, same is not working bash. what is ksh equalent in bash?

```
#!/bin/ksh

if [[ "$1" = @(hello|world|shell) ]] ; then
        echo "matched"
else
        echo "not matched"
fi
```

Thanks
SR

Comment: How about changing `#!/bin/ksh` to `#!/bin/bash`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable a subset of `ksh`'s extended pattern support (which, luckily for you, includes the `@(...)` construct :) with

```
 shopt -s extglob
 if [[ $1 = @(hello|world|shell) ]]; then
```

(`bash` 4.1 and later temporarily enable extended pattern support for `=` inside `[[...]]`, so the `shopt` command is only necessary in earlier versions of `bash`.)

Incidentally, you can achieve the same result with the POSIX-standard `case` statement.

```
case $1 in
    hello|world|shell) echo "matched" ;;
    * ) echo "not matched" ;;
esac
```